# Remove sorting in js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to remove sorting from this script part:

```
 getFirstAvailablePeriod() {
      const sortedPeriods = this.periods.sort((a: IPeriod, b: IPeriod) => {
        if (a.default_price.price === b.default_price.price) {
          return 0;
        }

        return (a.default_price.price > b.default_price.price) ? 1 : -1;
      }).filter((period: IPeriod) => !period.locked);

      const alreadySelected: IPeriod = sortedPeriods.find((period: IPeriod) => period.id === this.value);

      if (alreadySelected) {
        return alreadySelected;
      }

      return sortedPeriods[0];
    },

    async getPeriods() {
      const params: any = {};

      if (this.place === 'familyGrave' && this.type === 'multi') {
        params.funeral_id = this.item.funeralId;
      }

      await getPeriods(this.place, this.type, params).then((periods: IPeriod[]) => {
        this.periods = periods.sort((period: IPeriod, prev: IPeriod) => {
          if (period.sort === prev.sort) {
            return 0;
          }

          return period.sort - prev.sort;
        }).filter((period: IPeriod) => {
          return !((user()?.role || 'guest') !== 'super-admin' && !this.allowFree && `${period.default_price.price}` === '0');
        });

        if (!this.value) {
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.handleSelection(this.getFirstAvailablePeriod());
          });
        }
      });
    },
```

This script part reorder Periods from API. Plaese help me to remove rorting Periods from this script. My JS knownleadge is very bad.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `getFirstAvailablePeriod` instead of

```
const sortedPeriods = this.periods.sort((a: IPeriod, b: IPeriod) => {
    if (a.default_price.price === b.default_price.price) {
      return 0;
    }

    return (a.default_price.price > b.default_price.price) ? 1 : -1;
  }).filter((period: IPeriod) => !period.locked);
```

try this

```
const sortedPeriods = [...this.periods].sort((a: IPeriod, b: IPeriod) => {
    if (a.default_price.price === b.default_price.price) {
      return 0;
    }

    return (a.default_price.price > b.default_price.price) ? 1 : -1;
  }).filter((period: IPeriod) => !period.locked);
```

And to remove all sortings, delete sorting in `getPeroids`

```
 this.periods = periods.filter((period: IPeriod) => {
      return !((user()?.role || 'guest') !== 'super-admin' && !this.allowFree && `${period.default_price.price}` === '0');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part

```
.sort((period: IPeriod, prev: IPeriod) => {
      if (period.sort === prev.sort) {
        return 0;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed sorting. Give it a try.

```
getFirstAvailablePeriod() {
  const availablePeriods = this.periods.filter((period: IPeriod) => !period.locked);

  const alreadySelected: IPeriod = availablePeriods.find((period: IPeriod) => period.id === this.value);

  if (alreadySelected) {
    return alreadySelected;
  }

    return availablePeriods[0];
  },

async getPeriods() {
  const params: any = {};

  if (this.place === 'familyGrave' && this.type === 'multi') {
    params.funeral_id = this.item.funeralId;
  }

  await getPeriods(this.place, this.type, params).then((periods: IPeriod[]) => {
    this.periods = periods.filter((period: IPeriod) => {
      return !((user()?.role || 'guest') !== 'super-admin' && !this.allowFree && `${period.default_price.price}` === '0');
    });

    if (!this.value) {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.handleSelection(this.getFirstAvailablePeriod());
      });
    }
  });
},
```